# How to use kubectl proxy to verify a web server running in a pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm new in K8s and meet a problem.
After I create a pod, I wanna use `$ kubectl proxy` to verify the webserver running in the deployed Pod.
Here is the pod yaml file:

pod-example.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod-example
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
```

After I execute `$ kubectl proxy`, it shows like this:

```
$ kubectl proxy
Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001
```

But when I visit http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/dev/pods/pod-example/proxy/, it shows this:

```
kind    "Status"
apiVersion  "v1"
metadata    {}
status  "Failure"
message "pods \"pod-example\" not found"
reason  "NotFound"
details 
name    "pod-example"
kind    "pods"
code    404
```

The pod is running successfully, and the default "Welcome to nginx!" page should be visible... but I don't know what I did wrong.
Please help me, thx!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Get pod's namespace deployment:

   kubectl describe pod pod-example
2. Try:

   [http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/[PODS_NAMESPACE]/pods/pod-example/proxy/](http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/%5BPODS_NAMESPACE%5D/pods/pod-example/proxy/)